# I am getting empty array as a response when i do get request

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, express, mongoose

I am new to nodejs and express.When i try to do get request from the mongoose database in mlab.com i get an empty response.

my serve code is (app.js),

```
var  express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();
var db =mongoose.connect('mongodb://test:test@ds155695.mlab.com:55695/app');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function() {
console.log('we are connected');
});
var user = require('./model/userModel');
var routers = express.Router();
  routers.route('/getUSers').get(function(req,res){
     user.find(function(err,users){
       if(err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
          res.json(users);
      }
   });
});
 app.use('/api',routers);
 app.listen(8000,function() {
console.log('server working');
 });
```

My model is userModel.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = mongoose.Schema({
    firstName :  String,
    lastName : String
 });

 module.exports = mongoose.model('users',app);
```

can anyone help me where am i going wrong !

Comment: You might want to make sure your calling the getUSers correctly and ensure you not just falling through to a 404.

Comment: @PaulRyan yup i tested correctly , it shows 200

Comment: What is the console log result of the "users" object that you are returning over `res.json` and what is your full HTTP request? Both the URL and the body (if there is one) would be useful.

Comment: ok, I'm not a fan of mongoose and I don't use mlab however under the covers this is effectively doing a db.users.find({}) on that mlab mongo instance. You should ensure that query runs on your current db and returns a valid list of users. If not you should make sure there is something there.